# hive query is returning no data

Tags: hive, ibm-cloud, analytics-engine

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE invoiceitems (
  InvoiceNo INT,
  StockCode INT,
  Description STRING,
  Quantity INT,
  InvoiceDate BIGINT,
  UnitPrice DOUBLE,
  CustomerID INT,
  Country STRING,
  LineNo INT,
  InvoiceTime STRING,
  StoreID INT,
  TransactionID STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3a://streamingdata/data/*';
```

The data files were created by a spark structured streaming job:

```
...
data/part-00000-006fc42a-c6a1-42a2-af03-ae0c326b40bd-c000.json  7.1 KB  29/08/2018 10:27:32 PM  
data/part-00000-0075634b-8513-47b3-b5f8-19df8269cf9d-c000.json  1.3 KB  30/08/2018 10:47:32 AM  
data/part-00000-00b6b230-8bb3-49d1-a42e-ad768c1f9a94-c000.json  2.3 KB  30/08/2018 1:25:02 AM
...
```

Here is are the first few rows of the first file:

```
{"InvoiceNo":5421462,"StockCode":22426,"Description":"ENAMEL WASH BOWL CREAM","Quantity":8,"InvoiceDate":1535578020000,"UnitPrice":3.75,"CustomerID":13405,"Country":"United Kingdom","LineNo":6,"InvoiceTime":"21:27:00","StoreID":0,"TransactionID":"542146260180829"}
{"InvoiceNo":5501932,"StockCode":22170,"Description":"PICTURE FRAME WOOD TRIPLE PORTRAIT","Quantity":4,"InvoiceDate":1535578020000,"UnitPrice":6.75,"CustomerID":13952,"Country":"United Kingdom","LineNo":26,"InvoiceTime":"21:27:00","StoreID":0,"TransactionID":"5501932260180829"}
```

However, if I run the query, no data is returned:

```
hive> select * from invoiceitems limit 5;
OK
Time taken: 24.127 seconds
```

The log files for hive are empty:

```
$ ls /var/log/hive*
/var/log/hive:

/var/log/hive-hcatalog:

/var/log/hive2:
```

How can I debug this further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received more of a hint about the error when I ran:

```
select count(*) from invoiceitems;
```

This returned the following error

> ...
>
> DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1
>   killedVertices:1 FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed,
>   vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1535521291031_0011_1_00,
>   diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1535521291031_0011_1_00 [Map 1]
>   killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, Vertex Input:
>   invoiceitems initializer failed, vertex=vertex_1535521291031_0011_1_00
>   [Map 1], java.io.IOException: cannot find dir =
>   s3a://streamingdata/data/part-00000-006fc42a-c6a1-42a2-af03-ae0c326b40bd-c000.json
>   in pathToPartitionInfo: [s3a://streamingdata/data/*]

I decided to change the create table definition from:

```
LOCATION 's3a://streamingdata/data/*';
```

to

```
LOCATION 's3a://streamingdata/data/';
```

and this fixed the issue.